# semistability of an extension of bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Is there a non-semistable bundle of rank $3$ and degree $1$ which is an extension of a stable bundle of rank $2$ degree $1$ by a stable bundle of rank $1$  degree $0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On an elliptic curve $C$, take $$V=E_2(p) \oplus \mathcal{O}_C,$$ where $p \in C$ is a point and $E_2(p)$ is the unique non-split extension $$0 \to \mathcal{O}_C \to E_2(p) \to \mathcal{O}_C(p) \to 0. $$

The rank $2$ subbundle $W=E_2(p)$ strictly destabilizes $V$, because $$\mu(W)=\frac{1}{2} > \frac{1}{3} = \mu(V).$$

Comment: This is the only example in the sense that V can not be a non-split extension of rank 2 degree 1 bundle and a rank 1 degree 0 bundle. Also the SCSS subbundle could only be a rank 2 degree 1 bundle.

Comment: Maybe you mean that this is the only example *on an elliptic curve*?

Comment: No i mean for all curves it can only be such a split extension. This is becasuse in my hypothesis, the rank 2 degree 1 bundle is stable.